# How am I supposed to install El Capitan on a new SSD without recovery partition?

Tags: macos, install, mac-appstore

My old mac's hdd died. It's dead. So I got a ssd and installed it in the macbook.

Now how do I get El Capitan on there? I find lots of tips online that speak of creating a bootable USB drive from the Capitan installer. But I can't download the El Capitan from the appstore because the mac has got nothing to boot from.

On my newer macbook running Catalina, I also cannot download El Capitan from the appstore because it doesn't show up when searching for it.

What I did download is El Capitan's InstallMacOSX.dmg via https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886

But now I need to run/open this on the old mac with the fresh ssd.

I feel I'm stuck in a loop. I need a working OS to install an OS.....

Who can help me out here?

Comment: Let me test with El Capitan, and I will share with you the results. I have done with High Sierra on the latest Catalina one.

Comment: Even without a Recovery partition, you should be able to use Internet Recovery - it's in the firmware, not on disk.

Comment: Like @Tetsujin said, Internet Recovery still works. If you hold COMMAND-OPTION-R at startup you should get the latest build of macOS your mac supports

Comment: It's a macbookpro5,4 from mid 2009. It has no internet recovery.

Answer (score 2):

You said you downloaded the installer. Did you download it to another Mac? If so, mount the .DMG, copy the install file to the Applications folder, then follow this documentation:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372

Once the new SSD is installed, and you've created the bootable USB drive - insert USB drive into the Mac, start it up holding the alt (option) key, and select the Install El Captian drive.

Format the SSD from Disk Utility, then install.

Comment: Like I stated in my question, the download I was able to do was for "InstallMacOSX.dmg". That's not the same as the version downloaded from the appstore and used in the support link you gave.... 
It contains a InstallMacOSX.pkg file which itself contains InstallESD.dmg, but no createinstallmedia can be found....